# Can you create transient DI service inside of middleware?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic, dependency-injection

I am calling a purchased package, which I do not have source code for.  It is expecting a service pre-configured through DI.   I can't change this.

I don't know all of the parameters for the service until the user logs on.   User 'A' might have a different configuration than User 'B'.  If no user is logged in, then the service needs to be a different way.

I can't inject it during 'Startup', as it will be configured differently for 'A' and 'B' (and 'no user')

The best place (I think) to do it is during Middleware 'Invoke', however, I can't seem to get access to IServicesCollection to perform '.AddTransient<>'

Is this even possible?

Or is there a better way to create an '.AddTransient' service dynamically?

Comment: Do you really need it to be transient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If intending to access the service within the middleware invoke then there is no need to try and access `ServiceCollection` outside of Startup

register desired transient service using deferred factory delegate

```
//...

services.AddTransient<IService>(sp => {
    var ctx = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    var user = //get user however you intended to get user

    //create instance of service
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Service>(sp, user);        
});

//...
```

In the middleware the service can be explicitly injected via method injection

```
//...

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IService service) {
    //...
}

//...
```

Additional parameters for the middleware's `InvokeAsync`, after `HttpContext` are populated by dependency injection (DI).

This will in turn resolve your transient service when injecting into the member

Comment: Holy cow!!!  I was not aware this was an option!!!

This gives me EXACTLY what I need!!  Perfect!!

Thank you so much!!